# MessagePack and UnitsNet serialization error

Tags: msgpack

For UnitsNet Serialization by messagepack we create IMessagePackFormatter as below:

```
public class UnitInfoFormatter : IMessagePackFormatter<UnitInfo>
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings? jsonSerializerSettings;
        public UnitInfoFormatter()
        {
            jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
            jsonSerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new UnitsNetIQuantityJsonConverter());
        }

        public UnitInfo Deserialize(ref MessagePackReader reader, MessagePackSerializerOptions options)
        {
            var y = reader.ReadBytes();

        var yyy = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(y.Value);
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UnitInfo>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(y.Value), jsonSerializerSettings);

        return obj;
        }

        public void Serialize(ref MessagePackWriter writer, UnitInfo value, MessagePackSerializerOptions options)
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, jsonSerializerSettings);
            writer.WriteString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
        }
         
    }
```

and test object as below

```
[MessagePackObject]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [Key(0)]
        [MessagePackFormatter(typeof(UnitInfoFormatter))]
        public UnitInfo MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

then registration of resolver :

```
    var options = MessagePackSerializerOptions.Standard.WithResolver(
        CompositeResolver.Create(
            new IMessagePackFormatter[] { new StringInterningFormatter(), new UnitInfoFormatter() },
            new IFormatterResolver[] { StandardResolver.Instance }));
```

and create fake object for property

```
 var unitInfo11 = new UnitInfo<LengthUnit>(LengthUnit.Meter, "Meters", new BaseUnits(LengthUnit.Meter));

  TestClass d = new() { MyProperty = unitInfo11 };
```

and try to test

```
   var options = MessagePackSerializerOptions.Standard.WithResolver(
            CompositeResolver.Create(
                new IMessagePackFormatter[] { new StringInterningFormatter(), new UnitInfoFormatter() },
                new IFormatterResolver[] { StandardResolver.Instance }));

 TestClass d = new() { MyProperty = unitInfo11 };
        var ser = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(d, options);
        var des = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<TestClass>(ser, options);
```

finally we got

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Enum'.
```

error rise on Deserialize method of IMessagePackFormatter

how to solve it ?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

MessagePack does not natively support serializing .NET enums, thats because you have this error

you can change your deserealizer into:

```
public UnitInfo Deserialize(ref MessagePackReader reader, MessagePackSerializerOptions options)
{
    var count = reader.ReadArrayHeader();
    var unit = (LengthUnit)reader.ReadInt32();
    var abbreviation = reader.ReadString();
    var baseUnit = reader.ReadMessagePackObject<BaseUnits>();

    return new UnitInfo<LengthUnit>(unit, abbreviation, baseUnit);
}
```